# Can't use my phone as a folder path in windows

Tags: android, storage, windows-explorer, file-browser

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFRZ6.png)
I connect my phone to to my laptop and I want to use an app called **SyncFolders** to sync a folder between my laptop and my Android phone (I don't really know any better way to do this, if you do, I'll be glad if you tell me about the best way). But in the browser window to choose folders, I don't see my phone. Recently, I've had this problem in another app too. What should I do?
I can go and see files in my phone through Windows File Explorer and make changes there; but the problems is that there is no specified path to my android phone's storage in Windows File Explorer.

I head to diskmgmt.msc to see if my phone appeared there; It didn't.
[diskmgmt.msc screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjScv.png)

Comment: The phone is accessed via MTP and Windows is known to only integrate MTP devices without drive letter. You need third party software for a drive letter, but be aware that MTP is an all and simple protocol which has a lot of limitations so it will never work like a real drive. See also https://superuser.com/q/369959

Comment: The duplicate question is about Android only but that makes no difference as always MTP protocol.is used.